# How re-import music in Noise?

Tags: music

After a fresh install of Loki, I go to point Noise to my existing music folder but I can't select the folder at all. Same with import, selecting a folder (or audio file for that matter) does not seem to work for me.
I remember in Freya selecting a folder and hitting "enter" or something would immediately begin import.

Anything I might be missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem here!
And I even couldn't change the music folder location. How did you confirm your selection of the folder? I just move the desired folder, but nowhere i can confirm to execute the action. Seems there is a button of confirmation missed. Actually the same problem is it when you trying to import music and videos(into Videos). I am not sure should I to execute the action by hot key or anyway else. Is it a different way of operating it? I feel very weird of this have no idea what is the right way of operation.

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to figure it out. For anyone else who has been having trouble importing music into Noise, follow these steps:

- Open Noise settings
- Preferences
- Music Folder Location: (Default: Music)

Then change the default location and it will begin loading from what was previously selected.

In my case, I had all my music in the music folder which was not being imported. When I went to change this setting I flipped the option to Downloads and then it immediately started importing the music from the Music folder.

Hope this helps anyone else having this issue!

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the entire database in ~/.local/share/noise/

Noise will then re-scan everything. This is not an ideal solution, an option would be great.